# How to stop foreign language keyboard setting from automatically changing and having some keys mapped wrong?

Tags: windows-7, language

I have a English version of Windows 7 Home, but for personalization, I have set it to Polish.

I see weird behavior using this language, where some basic letters are substituted, like z=y, etc. 
There is a EN link in my taskbar where I can switch it English, or Polish (programming) both of which show the same correct letters.

2 problems:
- In Polish (214) mode, lots of keys are mapped incorrectly
- if I switch it back to English using the shortcut in taskbar, it automatically goes back to Polish (214) sometimes

At this point, I would rather it just didn't have any such options and stayed English.

Comment: Remove Polish (214) mode. I find it useless.

Comment: remove it how ?

Comment: I added answer on how to remove unwanted keyboard layouts from windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

To remove keyboard layout go to 'Control Panel', 'Change keyboards or other input methods', click 'Change keyboards' button and you have keyboard layout settings window.

Now you can set default keyboard layout which you want and then delete those not used.